# How to Deserialize an JArray?

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I need to deserialize and get child value of a JSON (Jarray) string

```
string initialJson = File.ReadAllText(Application.StartupPath + "\\Coda.json");
```

In this case is:

```
[
    "Scan",
    [
        "4eba277ef42fe2aeb6e3ac17ba00b784",
        {
            "ID":0,
            "Link":"https://www.virustotal.com/file/9416fbb8043d6eb6b544a79e51494a9181c/analysis/1556298405/",
            "ScanID":"9416fbb804db12002c39d6eb6b544a79e51494a9181c-1556298405"
        }
    ],
    [
        "80434f3307d5f66ce3548c6a3c735f34",
        {
            "ID":1,
            "Link":"https://www.virustotal.com/file/63fe7b058c20f39a579a94e56c85638ba7cd6f9f/analysis/1556298411/",
            "ScanID":"63fe7b058c20f3524760728294e56c85638ba7cd6f9f-1556298411"
        }
    ]
]
```

And convert with :

```
JArray jsonArray = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JArray>(initialJson);
```

After this i start a foreach:

```
foreach (JObject item in jsonArray.Children<JObject>())
            {
                foreach (JProperty element in item.Properties())
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(element.Name + " " + element.Value);
                }
            }
```

But nothing appear, no messagebox, no error, why?

I need to get the all value or first value and delete it

Comment: The structure here isn't being parsed as JObject. If you breakpoint and examine jsonArray and looks at jsonArray.Children() you will see 3 children. One is type string, two are type Array. What were you going for here?

Comment: [JArray](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JArray.htm) contains `JToken` objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JArray inside JArray, than JToken objects:

```
foreach (JArray item in jsonArray.Children<JArray>())
{
    foreach (JToken element in item.Children())
    {
        foreach(JProperty prop in element){

            prop.Value.Dump(prop.Name);

        }
    }
}
```

[image]